# When does a query/subquery return a NULL and when no value at all?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

1. If a query/subquery doesn’t find any matching rows, then it either returns NULL or no value at all, thus not even a NULL value. Based on
   what criteria does a query/subquery return a NULL and when doesn’t it return any results, not even a NULL value?
2. Will a scalar subquery always return NULL, when no
   matching rows are found? I assume most-outer scalar query also returns
   NULL if no rows are found?
3. ```
   SELECT FirstName, LastName, YEAR(BirthDate)
   FROM Persons
   WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) IN (SELECT YearReleased FROM Albums);
   ```

   - If the subquery finds no results, is the WHERE clause of the outer
     query translated into `WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) IN (null);`?
   - If WHERE clause is translated into `WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) IN();` instead, shouldn’t that be an error condition, since how can `YEAR(BirthDate)` value be compared to nothing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subquery would only ever return `NULL` when `YearReleased` was `NULL`, otherwise there would be an empty recordset, making it the `IN ()` case you mentioned.

It's very important to distinguish between the two as they mean entirely different things.  `NULL` indicates that there was something to be `SELECT`ed, although that value indicates a "lack of value" so to speak.  An empty recordset indicates that there was nothing to be selected that matched the criteria specified.

**EDIT**: updated to show example results

[image]

First two queries are just to show what's in the two tables.  Third query is your query and the fourth query just shows that it produces an equivalent result (no rows) if you replace the subquery with a `NULL`.  Last query is just to show that the subquery itself just returns a big list of `NULL`s.

Comment: “The subquery would only ever return NULL when YearReleased was NULL, otherwise there would be an empty recordset, making it the IN () case you mentioned.”

In other words, if Albums table contains only rows ( say 10 rows) with their YearReleased field set to NULL, then subquery should produce a result set of 10 rows and WHERE clause of an outer query should be translated into WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) IN (null)?!

Comment: See the edit, but yeah that's the where clause would essentially become `WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) IN (NULL)`.

Comment: I already marked your post as an answer, but if you find the time --> Assuming Albums table contains no rows, then SELECT MAX(CDPrice) FROM Albums; query will still produce a result set (a single row), since return value ( NULL ) of a MAX function is considered a row?!

Answer (score 2):

a.  If there are no matching rows, then the result set will always be empty.  There isn't any special handling for the NULL value.

b.  That's not true.  If there are no matching rows, then the result set is always empty by definition.  The result of a scalar function is not a result set so it will either be NULL or another value.

c.1. If the subquery doesn't return any rows then the "IN" expression will always return false.  The set will not be `NULL`.

c.2. It is valid to compare `YEAR(BirthDate)` with an empty set.  It will just always return false.

Comment: A)“c.1. If the subquery doesn't return any rows then the "IN" expression will always return false. The set will not be NULL.”

I assume if Albums table contains only rows ( say 10 rows) with their YearReleased field set to NULL, then subquery should produce a result set of 10 rows and WHERE clause of an outer query should be translated into WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) IN (null);?!

B) Assuming Albums table contains no rows, then SELECT MAX(CDPrice)
FROM  Albums; query will still produce a result set (a single row), since return value ( NULL ) of a MAX function is considered a row?!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, YEAR(BirthDate)
FROM Persons a
left join (SELECT YearReleased FROM Albums) b on year(b.YearReleased) = year(a.BirthDate)
where year(b.YearReleased) = year(a.BirthDate)
```

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the OPs clearly stated questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of subquery in SQL, and which one you get (and the resulting behaviour) depends on the context. If the `(subquery)` syntax is used, say, as an operand in most expression contexts, this is a scalar subquery. On the other hand, as the right operand of the `IN` operator, it is a table subquery.

For a scalar subquery:
If the subquery returns no rows, the result of the scalar subquery is `NULL`.
If the subquery returns more than one row, it is an error.
If the subquery returns one row, the result is the value of the query's (only) column for that row.

For a table subquery:
If the subquery returns no rows, the result is an empty set of values, so for instance the `IN` operation would always return false.
Otherwise, the result is the set of the query's column for all the rows.

So to address your questions individually:

1. It depends on the context of the subquery
2. Yes, a scalar subquery always returns `NULL` if there are no rows
   found
3. In the context of the `IN` operation it is a table subquery and
   so no rows means no values to match against. Note however that, due
   to the semantics of `IN` if your query returns a row where the query
   column value is itself `NULL`, you will have a `NULL` in your
   compare set. The `IN` operation is effectively the `OR` of equality
   comparisons between the left operand and each value individually in
   the right-hand value set. Null values in the set will result in
   "unknown" rather than true or false, and so the `IN` operation can
   only ever return true (if there is a match to some non-null value in
   the set) or unknown (because the value may or may not match null).