# Why does COALESCE not return null here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was bitten by a coalesce-returns-null issue before, that's covered by this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165295/why-coalesce-within-a-subquery-returns-null.

To improve my understanding I wanted a simpler example:

```
create table tbl(col int);
```

then

```
SELECT col
FROM tbl
-- returns nothing of course, tbl is empty
```

So in this following code, coalesce has a *nothing-there* to coalesce with, so it should return either nothing (no result set), or perhaps a single null.

```
select coalesce(
(
    SELECT col
    FROM tbl
), 22)
```

But run it and I get 22. Why does it work when I think it shouldn't?

(tested in SQL Server/TSQL)

Comment: Coalesce simply returns the first non-null value in your list, from left to right. It will never return a null as long as any single value is not null.

Comment: @stu - please see the attached SO answer, where this does in fact happen because the first expression is NOT a null. I'd expect the same here.

Comment: Yes I understand your conundrum I hadn't realised your tbl was (presumably) empty. That's a similar scenario to where you might try assigning a count to a variable and get a null rather than 0 if no rows are returned.

Comment: you need to add a default value to coalesce or it will return null if all arguments are null.  coalesce(arg1,arg2,arg3) where arg3 is "Unknown"

Comment: coalesce looks for the first non null value in the parameter list, if non is found it outputs NULL.  you want to have a default value in the parameter list of 'unknown'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this query:

```
select coalesce( (SELECT col FROM tbl), 22)
-----------------^ subquery
```

The subquery is a *scalar subquery*.  That is, it is being used in place of a constant.  A scalar subquery has the following properties:

- Returns one column.
- Returns zero or one rows.
- If it returns zero rows, then the value is `NULL`.

The third of these is why you get `NULL` so `COALESCE()` returns the second argument.

Note that if `tbl` had more than one row, then you would get an error, presumably of the form "scalar subquery returns more than one row".  This would be true even if the values in `col2` were all `NULL`.

Comment: Upvoted, will chew over and likely accept answer tomorrow.. Given your answer I could find other similar questions <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723806/when-does-a-query-subquery-return-a-null-and-when-no-value-at-all> & <https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238945/why-is-an-empty-rowset-not-equivalent-to-null-when-assigning-a-query-result-to-a> - FYI for other readers. I've done SQL for yonks and didn't know your 3rd rule.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a subquery used in an outer `select` or comparison operator must return exactly 1 column and 0 or 1 rows. If it returns more it is an error. But if it returns 0 values, it is converted to a `null` expression. Therefore:

```sql
(
    SELECT col
    FROM tbl
)
```

inside an outer `select` evaluates to `null`.

Placing that inside the `coalesce` means that you now have `null` and `22`. So `22` is returned.

```sql
select coalesce(
(
    SELECT col
    FROM tbl
), 22)
```

Whereas if the `coalesce` was *inside* the subquery, the semantic is completely different. Here, the subquery will return either 0 or 1 results. If it has a result then it will be `coalesce`d with `22`. But if there is no result then it can't be coalesced, therefore a `null` will be returned to the outer query.

```sql
select 
(
    SELECT coalesce(col, 22)
    FROM tbl
)
```

Answer (score 0):

because when coalesce evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't **evaluate** to NULL !

what you are looking for is :

```
select coalesce(col, 22)
from tbl
```

Comment: Yes. But the point is - and is illustrated by the other SO answer - the first expression here, the subquery, IS NOT A NULL. It's an empty result set. This is what the other SO answer explains. I'd expect the same behaviour here.